# How to get the item created from dropEvent on a qlistwidget

Tags: python, drag-and-drop, pyqt, qlistwidget, qlistwidgetitem

So I'm trying to copy a selected item from one QListWidget to another using drag and drop.

Anyway I could probably hack together what I need to by passing serialized parameters using item.setData but I can't figure out a straight forward way to get a handle on the new item being created in the second listWidget.

I guess I could look at all the items in the second QListWidget and somehow determine which one was just created but it seems like there should be an easier way to know which item is being created by the drop event.

```
import sys
from PyQt4 import QtGui , QtCore


def main():

    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)

    w = QtGui.QWidget()
    w.resize(250, 150)
    w.move(300, 300)
    w.setWindowTitle('Simple')
    layout=QtGui.QHBoxLayout(w)
    dragList=DragDropListWidget()
    layout.addWidget(dragList)
    dragList.setDragDropMode(QtGui.QAbstractItemView.InternalMove)
    dragList.name='dragList'
    dragList.populate(['one','two','three'])
    dragList2=DragDropListWidget()
    dragList2.setDragDropMode(QtGui.QAbstractItemView.DragDrop)
    dragList2.name='dragList'


    layout.addWidget(dragList2)
    w.show()

    sys.exit(app.exec_())

class scriptsWidget(QtGui.QWidget):


    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QtGui.QWidget.__init__(self)

        self.name=''

        self.widget_QHBoxLayout = QtGui.QHBoxLayout(self)
        self.widget_QHBoxLayout.setSpacing(0)
        self.widget_QHBoxLayout.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)

        self.name_QLabel = QtGui.QLabel(self)
        self.widget_QHBoxLayout.addWidget(self.name_QLabel)

        self.user_QLabel = QtGui.QLabel(self)
        self.widget_QHBoxLayout.addWidget(self.user_QLabel)

        self.widget_QHBoxLayout.setSpacing(0)
        self.widget_QHBoxLayout.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)



    def setName(self,name):
        self.name_QLabel.setText(name)
        self.name=name

    def setUser(self,user):
        self.user_QLabel.setText(user)

class customQListWidgetItem(QtGui.QListWidgetItem):


    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QtGui.QWidget.__init__(self)
        self.name=''

    def setName(self,name):
        self.name=name   




class DragDropListWidget(QtGui.QListWidget):
    _drag_info = []
    def __init__(self, parent = None):

        super(DragDropListWidget, self).__init__(parent)


        self.name=''


    def dragMoveEvent(self, event):
        if event.mimeData().hasUrls():
            event.setDropAction(QtCore.Qt.CopyAction)
            event.accept()

        else:
            super(DragDropListWidget, self).dragMoveEvent(event)


    def dropEvent(self, event):
        print('dropEvent') 
        print event.mimeData().text()

        if event.mimeData().hasText():
            print event.mimeData().text()
            event.setDropAction(QtCore.Qt.CopyAction)
            event.accept()
            links = []
            for url in event.mimeData().urls():
                links.append(str(url.toLocalFile()))
            self.emit(QtCore.SIGNAL("dropped"), links)

        else:
            event.setDropAction(QtCore.Qt.CopyAction)
            super(DragDropListWidget, self).dropEvent(event)
            items = []
            for index in xrange(self.count()):
                items.append(self.item(index))
                print self.item(index).data(QtCore.Qt.UserRole).toPyObject()



    def populate(self,items=[]):
        self.clear()
        for i in items:
            print(i)
            widget = scriptsWidget()
            widget.setName(i)
            widget.setUser('x')
            item = customQListWidgetItem()
            item.setName(i)
            data = (i)
            item.setData(QtCore.Qt.UserRole, data)
            self.addItem(item)
            self.setItemWidget(item,widget)



if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Interesting .. well my solution ended up being to store a list of items in the second  listwidget before and then do a comparison after the new item is added which works well enough and takes only a few lines of code. Then I pass the new item to a function that creates the item using the same classes that were used when it was created in the first listwidget and I passed serialized info about in .data(QtCore.Qt.UserRole)

```
def dropEvent(self, event):
    if event.mimeData().hasText():
        event.setDropAction(QtCore.Qt.CopyAction)
        event.accept()
        links = []
        for url in event.mimeData().urls():
            links.append(str(url.toLocalFile()))
        self.emit(QtCore.SIGNAL("dropped"), links)

    else:
        event.setDropAction(QtCore.Qt.CopyAction)
        items = []
        for index in xrange(self.count()):
            items.append(self.item(index))

        super(DragDropListWidget, self).dropEvent(event)

        for index in xrange(self.count()):
            if self.item(index) not in items:
                self.populateDrop(self.item(index), index, [self.item(index).data(QtCore.Qt.UserRole).toPyObject()])

def populateDrop(self,item,row,items=[]):
    for i in items:
        widget = scriptsWidget()
        widget.setName(i)
        widget.setUser('x')
        self.takeItem(row)
        item = customQListWidgetItem()
        item.setName(i)
        item.setWhatsThis(i)
        data = (i)
        item.setData(QtCore.Qt.UserRole, data)
        self.insertItem (row, item)
        self.setItemWidget(item,widget)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can connect to the [`rowsInserted`](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/qabstractitemmodel.html#rowsInserted) signal on the listview model

```
class DragDropListWidget(...):

    def __init__(...):
        ...
        self._dropping = False
        self.model().rowsInserted.connect(self.on_rowsInserted)

    def on_rowsInserted(self, parent_index, start, end):
        if self._dropping:
            # Recently dropped items
            items = [self.item(i) for i in range(start, end + 1)]

    def dropEvent(self, event):
        self._dropping = True
        # code that drops the new rows
        ...
        self._dropping = False
```

Comment: I checked this out before I didn't really help. I'd still need to compare the list before and after the drop in order to know what the index is of the new item.

Comment: @obfuscated The `on_rowsInserted` callback should only be triggered for the new items.

Comment: That may be so but the other problem is that if the item originated in the same list I need to move the item instead of copying it (I want to copy the item if it originated in the other list).